# diagnose nvidia-525 driver brightness control

Tags: nvidia, 22.04, brightness

i have a problem with my brightness controlling in Ubuntu 22.04 and actually i cant find where is it comes from. i have a disordering brightness level when i try to change it. the brightness level decrease normally but at its low values, it goes high and again comes down. think its better to show you the value of `/sys/class/backlight/nvidia_0/actual_backlight` when i try to increase it:
[level of brightness](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1hR7D.png)

and [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QupET.png) is the outputs of `uname -a` , `lspci | grep -Ei nvidia` , `nvidia-detector` , `sudo apt list --installed | grep -i nvidia-525`

thank you if you can help me fix it.